# Loop Through DataFrame to Select Specific Cells in Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, text

I am attempting to create a loop function to loop through my dataframe in python in order to compare text documents for a count vectorizer method and other similar comparison functions.

I have data of movie franchises and want to compare the plot of each sequel to the original film in the franchise, as well as the previous film in the franchise. I have attached a snippet of the data. For example, I want Seq 1 in FranID 1 to be compared to Seq 0 in FranID 1 and have this continue for each sequel and franchise. I would want Seq 2,3,4,5,etc. to be compared to Seq 0 within each FranID.

In addition, I would want a separate loop that compared each sequel to the previous film within each franchise. For example, I want to compare Seq 1 to Seq 0 and Seq 2 to Seq 1, etc.

Is there a way I can loop through the data in such for to implement it into this code or similar and then add it to the dataframe as a new variable for each film:

```
def cosine_distance_countvectorizer_method(s1, s2):

# sentences to list
allsentences = [s1 , s2]

# packages
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from scipy.spatial import distance

# text to vector
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
all_sentences_to_vector = vectorizer.fit_transform(allsentences)
text_to_vector_v1 = all_sentences_to_vector.toarray()[0].tolist()
text_to_vector_v2 = all_sentences_to_vector.toarray()[1].tolist()

# distance of similarity
cosine = distance.cosine(text_to_vector_v1, text_to_vector_v2)
print('Similarity of two sentences are equal to ',round((1-cosine)*100,2),'%')
return cosine
```

Next line:

```
cosine_distance_countvectorizer_method(ss1 , ss2)
```

Data example:

[image: Data example]

Comment: never use loops in dataframe. Try with loc, iloc

Comment: which cells would you like to select ? it is not so clear

Comment: @trillion I would like to compare the text of the "plot" cell of Seq 1 to Seq 0 for each FranID. For example, I want to compare observations 0 and 1. In addition, I would like to compare 906 to 905 as well as compare 905 to 904, etc.

Comment: Okay I may have made this easier but am still having difficulty with the code. I went in to create new columns for plot_prev and plot_orig. I want to compare each item in the "plot" column with "plot_prev" and "plot_orig". How can I define each cell in each column as s1 and s2 in my given code to go through the entire column? I added a new screenshot of the dataframe which I have now.

Comment: hey you would like to compare plot_prev and plot_org, is that a AND condition meaning retrun true if plot is equal to the plot_prev and plot_org ?\

Comment: comparison1 = df['plot'] == df['plot_org'] , comparison2 = df['plot'] == df['plot_prev']

Comment: final_ = df.loc[comaprison1 & comparison2]

Comment: the plot_prev and plot_org shows same values why is that ??

Comment: i am not sure what do you need exactly after comparing the results of plot with both plot org and plot prev. I have created a code to do the comparison and return the dataframe that meets the requirement. see the code below in answer

Comment: plot_orig and plot_prev are the same for many of the films, since if it is the first sequel the original film and previous film are the same....what I want to do is compare plot with plot _prev and get the results in one column and then also compare plot with plot_orig  and get the results in another column. I want to use my previous text comparison code to get the cosine distances between the comparisons I just mentioned. I just need to be able to loop through each row, defining plot as s1, and plot_prev as s2 and then add the results in a new column

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236864/discussion-between-trillion-and-bzh).

Comment: please join the chat using the link above

Answer (score 1):

based on the discussion in the chat here you go:

```
ss1 == df['plot']
ss2 == df['plot_prev']

to apply the function use args / kwargs
https://www.journaldev.com/33478/pandas-dataframe-apply-examples
```